# Select a Checkbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have developed a product catalogue front-end using ASP.NET, jQuery, JSON and jTemplates.

Basically, the front-end retrieves a paged set of products from the database using jQuery and JSON and displays the products on the front-end (one page at a time) using the jTemplate 'productItemTemplate' see below.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

var selectedProductIDs = '1, 2';

```
    function displayProductCheckboxes() {
        var productIDs = selectedProductIDs.split(", ");
        var checkboxes = $('input:checkbox[name="chkProduct"]');

        for (var j = 0; j < productIDs.length; j++) {
            checkboxes
            .filter('[id="' + productIDs[j] + '"]')
            .attr('checked', 'checked');
        };
    }
```

```
    <script type="text/html" id="productItemTemplate">    
        <ul class="items-list">        
        {#foreach $T.items as record}                                       
            <li class="item-detail">

              <a class="item-productimage-link" href="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Product/Detail.aspx?ProductID={$T.record.ProductSummaryViewID}") %>">
                <img class="item-productimage" src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Content/Images/Products/{$T.record.ProductSummaryViewID}.jpg") %>" />
              </a>

              <div class="item-productname">
                <a href="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Product/Detail.aspx?ProductID={$T.record.ProductSummaryViewID}") %>">{$T.record.BrandName} {$T.record.Name}</a>
              </div>

             <div class="item-price">{$T.record.Price}</div>

             <div><input type="checkbox" class="" name="chkProduct" id="{$T.record.ProductSummaryViewID}" onclick="JavaScript:selectProduct({$T.record.ProductSummaryViewID})"/>Select me!</label></div>

           </li>
           {#/for}  
        </ul>                  
    </script>
```

Each product has a checkbox 'chkProduct' - see above.  I would like the user to be able to select a product by clicking the associated checkbox and for the user's selection to be maintained across pages.

To achieve this I maintain a list of selected Product IDs 'selectedProductIDs' - see above.

Everytime I load a page of products I call the function 'displayProductCheckboxes()' which is meant to check the previously checked checkboxes.

Unfortuanetly. it doesn't check the previously checked checkboxes.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue please or suggest an alternative working solution.

Thanks.

Regards

Walter

Comment: Incidental and not part of the issue, but you've got a rogue </label> tag in your example after the checkbox - The <li>'s containing divs within them is also one to address.

Comment: What is this selectProduct is doing actually?.. Any Ajax call?

Comment: Abhijeet: JavaScript:selectProduct is a function where I maintain the list 'selectedProductIDs' - no Ajax call.

Comment: I created this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KFFM5/ - does this prove that the core of your jQuery code is fine and potentially that the HTML inaccuracies are to blame? Not entirely sure. Either way, hope it may help.... if selectedProductIds is set correctly then the checkboxes get checked

Comment: SpaceBison: thanks for spotting the rogue </label> tag.

Comment: is there a `$(document).ready()` or `$(function()` (equivalent) around the javascript portion?

Comment: Thanks SpaceBison the function is being called.

Comment: SpaceBison: Thanks for jsFiddle. I have removed the rogue </label> and the <div> and still it does not work.

Comment: SpaceBison: there is definitely something weird going on in my code. Do you think it would be possible to set the checkbox during the processing of the jTemplate?

Comment: if your code is within document.ready then it will be waiting for the entire page to be rendered before running it - I can't see how doing it during any other time is going to change the outcome, despite my unfamiliarity with the tech you're using. Not sure what else to suggest!

Comment: SpaceBison: thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery introduced the prop() method in version 1.6 as attr() has long been problematic in various situations. Use prop() instead of attr() for properties like "checked". "checked" is an element property not attribute

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem in IE. I've set the defaultChecked property.

checkBox.defaultChecked = true;

Comment: Sorry danpickett I don't understand how I can use this solution in the code snippet I provided above.

Answer (score 0):

Your example function is working correctly for me in FF 10.0.2 with jQuery 1.7.1. Maybe you are not calling the function `displayProductCheckboxes();`on `$(document).ready()`?

I built a small jsfiddle: [see it here](http://jsfiddle.net/CUC8d/).

Comment: Thanks Seybsen the function is being called.